# Double LinkedList in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been trying to implement double linked list in Python. I have a problem in removing a node from any given position. Please help. Below is my code.

```
class Double_linked_list:
    class Node:
        __slots__ = '_element', '_prev', '_next'

        def __init__(self, element, prev, next):
            self._element = element
            self._next = next
            self._prev = prev

    def __init__(self):
        self._head = self.Node(None, None, None)
        self._tail = self.Node(None, None, None)
        self._head._next = self._tail
        self._tail._prev = self._head
        self._size = 0

    def __len__(self):
        return self._size

    def is_empty(self):
        return self._size == 0

    def delete_any(self, pos):
        if self.is_empty():
            raise Empty('Linked List empty')
        thead = self._head
        i = 1
        while i < pos - 1:
            thead = thead._next
            i += 1
        value = thead._next._element
        thead._next = thead._next._next
        thead._next._next._prev = thead._prev
        self._size -= 1
        return value
```

Exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Abdullah Khan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3326, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-2-277dd1818f6d>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('C:/Users/Abdullah Khan/Documents/Python Learning/Starting from Scratch/data structures and algos/linkedlist/double_linked_list.py', wdir='C:/Users/Abdullah Khan/Documents/Python Learning/Starting from Scratch/data structures and algos/linkedlist')
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_bundle\pydev_umd.py", line 197, in runfile
    pydev_imports.execfile(filename, global_vars, local_vars)  # execute the script
  File "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm 2019.1.3\helpers\pydev\_pydev_imps\_pydev_execfile.py", line 18, in execfile
    exec(compile(contents+"\n", file, 'exec'), glob, loc)
  File "C:/Users/Abdullah Khan/Documents/Python Learning/Starting from Scratch/data structures and algos/linkedlist/double_linked_list.py", line 119, in <module>
    print("Deleted Any: ", dll.delete_any(3))
  File "C:/Users/Abdullah Khan/Documents/Python Learning/Starting from Scratch/data structures and algos/linkedlist/double_linked_list.py", line 90, in delete_any
    thead._next._next._prev = thead._prev
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_next'
```

Comment: You never check that ``pos`` is actually in the list. Is the linked list for which you get the error actually long enough?

Comment: Please include all the code required to reproduce the issue. See [mre]

Comment: I'm guessing you're hitting the end of your list. You probably need to have some checks that each of those `thead._next` items are not `None`. For instance, if you want to delete the second-to-last element in your list, `thead._next` is the last element, and `thead._next._next` is invalid. Ultimately it looks like you are assuming you have at least *three* `_next` elements in the list, `thead._next = thead._next._next` followed by `thead._next._next._prev` gives the original `thead._next._next._next._prev`.

Comment: @Engineero thanks I understand your answer but can you please help me with code. Thanks

Comment: We cannot help you with your code if you do not show us how to reproduce your error. We can *guess*  what is wrong - but unless you can actually define what you want to happen when ``pos`` is not in the list, we cannot fix that either.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're hitting the end of your list. You probably need to have some checks that each of those `thead._next` items are not `None`. For instance, if you want to delete the second-to-last element in your list, `thead._next` is the last element, and `thead._next._next` is `None`.

Ultimately it looks like you are assuming you have at least *three* `_next` elements in the list, `thead._next = thead._next._next` followed by `thead._next._next._prev` gives the original `thead._next._next._next._prev`.

Try this:

```
def delete_any(self, pos):
    if self.is_empty():
        raise Empty('Linked List empty')
    if pos > self._size - 1:
        # A one-element list only has position 0, thus size - 1.
        raise IndexError('Position is out of range')
    thead = self._head
    for i in range(pos - 1):
        # This should be fine as long as the above check passed.
        thead = thead._next
    value = thead._next._element
    thead._next = thead._next._next
    if thead._next._next is not None:
        # If you run off your list, you just don't have another element
        # on which to define `_prev`.
        thead._next._next._prev = thead._prev
    self._size -= 1
    return value
```

Note I couldn't run this without some example code to build the list and get your error. Let me know if there are issues and I'll try to correct them.

Also note that this won't work with a one-element list. You're assuming you can stand at the element *before* the one that you want to delete, but in a one-element list you can't do that. You might want to add code to handle that as a special case.

Comment: And If thead._next._next is None?

Comment: Then how will it set prev node address?

Comment: You don't. There's no element there to have a `_prev` node address. That's why that's in an `if` block and gets ignored if the object isn't there.

Answer (score 0):

**Look here this works fine**

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.item = data
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None
class doublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.start = None
    def InsertToEmptyList(self, data):
        if self.start is None:
            new_node = Node(data)
            self.start = new_node
        else:
            print("The list is empty")
    def InsertToEnd(self, data):
        # Check if the list is empty
        if self.start is None:
            new_node = Node(data)
            self.start = new_node
            return
        temp = self.start
        while temp.next is not None:
            temp = temp.next
        new_node = Node(data)
        temp.next = new_node
        new_node.prev = temp
    def DeleteAtStart(self):
        if self.start is None:
            print("The Linked list is empty, no element to delete")
            return 
        if self.start.next is None:
            self.start = None
            return
        self.start = self.start.next
        self.start_prev = None;
    def delete_at_end(self):
        # Check if the List is empty
        if self.start is None:
            print("The Linked list is empty, no element to delete")
            return 
        if self.start.next is None:
            self.start = None
            return
        temp = self.start
        while temp.next is not None:
            temp = temp.next
        temp.prev.next = None
    def delet_at_any(self,position):
        temp=self.start
        while position>2:
            temp=temp.next
            position-=1
        prev=temp
        temp.next=temp.next.next
        temp.prev=prev
    def Display(self):
        if self.start is None:
            print("The list is empty")
            return
        else:
            temp = self.start
            while temp is not None:
                print("Element is: ", temp.item)
                temp = temp.next
        print("\n")

NewDoublyLinkedList = doublyLinkedList()
NewDoublyLinkedList.InsertToEmptyList(10)
NewDoublyLinkedList.InsertToEnd(20)
NewDoublyLinkedList.InsertToEnd(30)
NewDoublyLinkedList.InsertToEnd(40)
NewDoublyLinkedList.InsertToEnd(50)
NewDoublyLinkedList.InsertToEnd(60)
NewDoublyLinkedList.Display()
NewDoublyLinkedList.DeleteAtStart()
NewDoublyLinkedList.DeleteAtStart()
NewDoublyLinkedList.delet_at_any(3)
NewDoublyLinkedList.Display()
```

Comment: Just you can remove the other methods if you don't want them.

Comment: Hi, it would be great if you could explain what your code does. It does make your answer a lot better and easier to understand for the rest of us!

Comment: def delet_at_any(self,position):
This method sets a position for the node to be removed. Then we set a temporary variable temp=self.start. Next we used a while loop which iterates through the doubly Linked List until it reaches the expected node. The position variable decreases in every iterations until it reaches one(1). The position variable reaches one means the expected node that has to be removed is achieved. Then we change the pointers here 
        prev=temp
        temp.next=temp.next.next
        temp.prev=prev

Comment: prev is a pointer like next pointers. prev pointer is points to the previous node.
next pointer is points to the next node. We changed the prev pointer points to the next previous node( node befor node). We changed the temp pointer points to the next of next node which means no more time is the next pointer points the removed node. 
After that the garbage collector removes the remaining unused node.(The node that has to be removed.) . I think it make sense. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
class node :
    def __init__(self, data):
        self. data = data
        self.next = None
        self.prev = None
    
class doubleLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        
    def insertNode(self, data):
        newNode = node(data)
        
        if self.head == None:
            self.head = newNode
        else:
            current = self.head
            while  current.next is not None:
                # prevNode = current
                current = current.next
            
            newNode.prev = current
            current.next = newNode
            
    def printDLL(self):
        current = self.head
        count = 0
        while current.next is not None:
            count+=1
            if count == 1:
                print("NONE<----",current.data,end="--->")
            else:
                print(current.data,end="--->")
                
            current = current.next
            
        if count ==0:
            print("NONE<----",current.data,'----> NONE')
        else:
             print(current.data,'----> NONE')
             
    def goToNode(self,data):
        current = self.head
        
        count = 1
        while current.next is not None:
            if count == data:
                print("cEntered node data :", current.data)
                print("prev node data :", current.prev.data)
                print("next node data :", current.next.data)
                break
            else:
                count+=1
                current = current.next
                 
        

l = doubleLinkedList()
l.insertNode(1)
l.insertNode(2)
l.insertNode(3)
l.insertNode(4)
l.insertNode(5)
l.insertNode(6)
l.insertNode(7)
l.insertNode(8)
l.printDLL()
l.goToNode(5)
```